# Initialization of Datatables for jQuery Returning Blank Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Using the initialization guide from [Datatables.net](https://www.datatables.net/manual/installation#Initialising-DataTables), no matter what changes I've tried the page is returned empty. I've tried hosting the files rather than using the CDN, updating to the most recent versions of jQuery, and searching for this but haven't seen anyone else with this error.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- Initialising DataTables -->
<?
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tableDataset').DataTable();
});
?>

<table id="tableDataset" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="/assets/plugins/dashboard/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code seems to work perfectly : https://jsfiddle.net/nr71raL7/

Comment: I get a 500 error when I include the <!-- Initialising DataTables --> php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrapped the jQuery onready function inside `php` open-end tags. Try changing it to the proper tag `<script></script>`. Also, if you load your javascript files at the bottom of the page, you have to append your functions after them.

Changing your current code to this one solves the problem ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/xgzq5zf1/)):

```
<!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!-- Initialising DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tableDataset').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @kmsdev! That's where the issue was created.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and try again

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <script src="/assets/plugins/dashboard/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table id="tableDataset" class="display">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <th>Column 1</th>
                   <th>Column 2</th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr>
                   <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                   <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                   <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('#tableDataset').DataTable();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```